# Typos in Getzler's "Short proof of local Atiyah-Singer index theorem"?

Tags: differential-topology

I am a physicist reading  Ezra Getzler's paper *A short proof of the local Atiyah-Singer index theorem*  (Topology 25 (1986) 111-117). The clever  step in his proof is his rescaling so as to focus of the short distance behaviour of the heat kernel for the 
 Lichnerowicz laplacian 
$$
{\rm Dirac}^2=g^{\mu\nu} (D_\mu D _\nu- {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}D_\lambda) +{\textstyle\frac 12}  F_{\mu\nu}   \gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu   - {\textstyle\frac 14}  R. 
$$
A key  equation is the rescaled version of Lichnerowicz which appears as  the equation before his numbered equation (5). His version reads
$$
D^\epsilon = g^{ij}(\epsilon x)\left( (\partial_i +  \epsilon^{-1} \Gamma_i(\epsilon x)\circ_\epsilon  +\epsilon A_i(\epsilon x)) (\partial_j +  \epsilon^{-1} \Gamma_j(\epsilon x)\circ_\epsilon+\epsilon A_\nu(\epsilon x))\right. \\
\left . + {\Gamma^k}_{ij}(\epsilon x) (\partial_k +  \epsilon^{-1}  \Gamma_j(\epsilon x)\circ_\epsilon   +\epsilon^{-1} A_k(\epsilon x))\right)+ {\frac 14}  F_{ab}(\epsilon x)(e^a\wedge e^b)\circ_\epsilon-  \frac {\epsilon^2} {4}R(\epsilon x).
$$ 
I get a slightly different expression:
$$
D^\epsilon = g^{ij}(\epsilon x)\left( (\partial_i +  \epsilon^{-1} \Gamma_i(\epsilon x)\circ_\epsilon  +\epsilon A_i(\epsilon x)) (\partial_j +  \epsilon^{-1} \Gamma_j(\epsilon x)\circ_\epsilon+\epsilon A_\nu(\epsilon x))\right. \\
\left . -\epsilon\, {\Gamma^k}_{ij}(\epsilon x) (\partial_k +  \epsilon^{-1}   \Gamma_j(\epsilon x)\circ_\epsilon   +\epsilon A_k(\epsilon x))\right)+ {\frac 14}  F_{ab}(\epsilon x)(e^a\wedge e^b)\circ_\epsilon-  \frac {\epsilon^2} {4}R(\epsilon x).
$$ 
The difference of sign before the ${\Gamma^k}_{ij}$ is insignificant and comes from his quoted version of Lichnerowicz, but the $\epsilon$ multiplying my ${\Gamma^k}_{ij}$ is absent in his expression. Its presence  seems to be necessary for the ${\Gamma^k}_{ij}$  term to vanish in the $\epsilon\to 0$ limit. Also, although not so important, is that  I do not see why there are  $\epsilon A_i$'s in his  first two gauge connection terms but an $\epsilon^{-1} A_k$ in its  third appearence in his expression.   I get $\epsilon A$'s in all three places. I find his notation hard to translate into my physics language, and I wonder if I have misunderstood something. Have I  made an error somewhere?  --- or are there typos in his text?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried contacting Getzler?